# Searching by Name in XML file through LINQ in C# and displaying in GridView

Tags: c#, xml, linq, search, gridview

Pretty new at this whole web development thing and a morning of google search and looking through stack overflow has pointed me in the right direction, but I'm still having issues.

I have an XML file, Bricks.xml, with the structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Links>
    <Table1
        Name="Bob Smith"
        Text="GO TEAM!!!"
        Location="Tennis Court"
    />
</Links>
```

I have a text box, (txtName) and a Button (btnSearch).  I would like to be able to take the input from txtName.text and display it in my grid view.  I currently have this all set up in panels with one panel for the txtName and btnSearch, which is always visible.  I have another panel with the grid view that pulls the whole XML file, and finally a third panel with the same grid view which I intended to use as the "search results."  I would think it would be possible to get read of that, and just reload the gridview that is already displayed.

Answer (score 0):

So you would want to do something like this to search through the nodes to find one that has a specific name.  Then you just need to do whatever you want with the results ...

```
string nameToSearch = "Bob";
string rawXML = null;

using (var stream = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("<YOUR_FILE_PATH>")))
{
    rawXML = stream.ReadToEnd();
}

if (rawXML != null)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(rawXML);
    XElement foundNode = doc.Descendants("Table1").Where(n => n.Attribute("Name").Value.Contains(nameToSearch)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (foundNode != null)
    {
        string name     = foundNode.Attribute("Name").Value;
        string text     = foundNode.Attribute("Text").Value;
        string location = foundNode.Attribute("Location").Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked great.  I jumped off from here, and already have added a lot of functionality this way.  I never thought of using StreamReader to parse the file.

Comment: Now I've actually ran into another problem.  I cant seem to get StreamReader to parse my XML because it dosn't like URIs

Comment: Disregaurd, dropped some of this in to make it work properly.  http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2140.htm